lua: Usar type annotations de uma biblioteca
Existe alguma forma de eu conseguir aproveitar o type annotations de uma biblioteca que instalei em lua?
No neovim, por exemplo, considerando o método:
---@param lhs string           Left-hand side |{lhs}| of the mapping.
---@param rhs string|function  Right-hand side |{rhs}| of the mapping, can be a Lua function.
---
---@param opts? vim.keymap.set.Opts
local function vim_keymap_set(lhs, rhs, opts)
    -- sobrepõe as opções padrão com as opções específicas da chamada à função
    opts = vim.tbl_extend('force', outer_opts, opts or {})
    vim.keymap.set(mode, lhs, rhs, opts)
end

eu sei que vim.keymap.set.Opts é o que método vim.keymap.set espera em opts e gostaria de poder aproveitar as próprias tipagens do neovim, mas:


P.S.: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/22287

